# Ubuntu Cython compilation error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, ubuntu, gcc, cython, digital-ocean

I have a Cython/Python Dash/Flask application I am trying to compile and deploy on Digitalocean.

I'd managed to deploy a prior version just fine - but after pulling the latest compilation now fails with:

```
building 'event' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/var/www/anagami/anagamienv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c event.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/event.o
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I'm using ubuntu 20 + python 3.8. The same code compiles and runs perfectly fine on windows, and a slightly earlier version used to compile and run jsut fine on ubuntu as well.

The compiler gets stuck on one particular extension for a really long time (like 15-20 minutes) and always gives that error.

What I've tried so far - nothing has worked:

- Deleting all .pyd .c .so files and the build folder recompiling fresh
- installing modules libpcap-dev & libpq-dev as suggested on threads with a similar issue
- sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev - same as above
- compiling on windows and trying to run the same code on linux without recompiling - program does not start giving the error that it cannot find the 'event' module which is where compilation fails
- nginx and the wsgi service are disabled, I'm not trying to overwrite any files that are in use
- program is pretty lightweight, so extremely unlikely any actual memory issues there

I'd run into this issue before, and that time just deleting + recompiling seemed to do the trick - but now I'm completely stuck - I've tried anything I could think of and I just have no solution to this.

UPDATE:

I have isolated the error by running `python3 event.pyx` and it gives the following:

```
cdef class master_event_table:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: give all steps you ran

Comment: I can't really think of anything else I did except the stuff in the bullet points. I've also tried adding import setuptoops in my setup.py. running py event.pyx standalone on windows also gives that cdef syntax error, but when I compile the whole app it works. Is there anything else in particular I can provide on steps I've done?

Comment: also discovered into another file, it had an issue with a few cdef str when running it standalone (these work fine on windows, and previously in this same program on ubuntu). I've removed them, so not 'syntax error' issues in any other files, only the cdef class in event, which still does not compile

Comment: I've discovered another 'syntax' error when I run an imported module standalone cp - this is the line (also used to work fine..): cpdef event_MOVE(input_settings):

Comment: `python3 event.pyx` would *never* be expected to work because you're trying it read it as a Python file. You want to run Cython on the file

Comment: I'm not really expecting it to work - it's just to try and figure out if there are any errors it's failing to display. the problem is that event.pyx won't compile

Comment: my program entry point is main.pyx - which when I used to compile everything works fine under py main.pyx or python3 main.py. event is a module

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the end was the cloud provider: the shared model at digitalocean seems to have some memory issues and the code just did not compile even though it was perfectly valid.

I ended up switching to the dedicated CPU plan and everything compiled and ran with no modifications.